# Is there a way to input a text from textbox1.text to input box of a website? I'm using a chromium browser in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to make a program in which I can input my username from my Visual basic project Textbox1 to facebook input box username. I'm using chromium from CefSharp for webbrowser. I got the id through 'view page source' which is 'email'. but what I'm not sure if my line of code is correct.

Here are my code so far:

```
Imports CefSharp
Imports CefSharp.Web
Imports CefSharp.JavascriptBinding
Imports CefSharp.Event

Public Class Form2

    Private WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

    Sub New()
         InitializeComponent()
        InitializeChromium() 
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeChromium()
        Dim settings As New CefSettings()
        CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)
        Dim browser As New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.facebook.com")
        Panel1.Controls.Add(browser)
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill 
    End Sub
 

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  
        browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').value='ansdew@gmail.com'")

    End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the error message

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

The line of code which this exception

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('email').value='ansdew@gmail.com'")
```

I don't know if the inside of this

> ExecuteScriptAsync

is correct and I need to find the correct script so I can input my username/email using my VB project.
Let me know also if I need to include some lines of code.

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the dim in front of browser so the class level instance is actually assigned

Comment: Hello  @amaitland,
Please add this as a solution as this awesomely fix my code! HAHA! Thank you so much and I really do appreciate it!